# Java Nested If condition

Tags: java, if-statement

I need to have nested **if condition** but i see my code has the same logic for the else portion as well.

Syntax

```
if(outer_condition){
    if(inner_condition){

    }
    else{
        employee.setCompany("ABC");
        employee.setAddress("DEF");
    }
}
else{
    employee.setCompany("ABC");
    employee.setAddress("DEF");
}
```

Both Else portion has to execute the same logic, is there a way to avoid this and make single Else condition ?

Thanks

Comment: Make it a single `if` condition by joining both conditions with an `&&` operator.

Comment: use if-else-if ladder or join conditions by using && operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine both conditions with && operator.

```
   if (condition1 && condition2) {
      // If both conditions code
   } else {
        employee.setCompany("ABC");
        employee.setAddress("DEF");
   }
```

**Note** If the code of the if statement is absent as it seams from your code is better to replace it with

```
if (!condition1 || !condition2) {
    employee.setCompany("ABC");
    employee.setAddress("DEF");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(condition) // condition_1
    {

        if(condition) // condition_2
            {
                // your code 1
            }
        else
            {
               // your code 2
            }
    }
    else
    {
        // your code 2
    }
```

Change the above code to this...

```
 if (condition_1 && condition_2) {
     // your code 1
   } else {
      // your code 2
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say if you define your first condition as condition1 and other as condition2, you could use this:

```
if (condition1 && condition2) {
  ifBlockCode();
} else {
   elseBlockCode();
}

public void elseBlockCode() {
    employee.setCompany("ABC");
    employee.setAddress("DEF");
}

public void ifBlockCode() {
    // Your logic can go here.
}
```

The `&&` used here is the logical and operator. Similarly, there are logical or, not, etc operators. You could read about those online.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(condition1){
    if(condition2){
       //no code here
    }
    else{
       codesnippet1;
    }
}
else{
    codesnippet1; //same as snippet encountered above
}
```

Cases :

Case1. condition1 true and condition2 true  -> //no code here

Case2. condition1 true and condition2 false -> //codesnippet1

Case3. condition1 false and condition2 true -> //codesnippet1

Case4. condition1 false and condition1 false-> //codesnippet1

So only if both conditions are true code doesn't execute codesnippet1

Hence you can simplify as

```
if(condition1 && condition2 )
{

}
else
{
   codesnippet1;
}
```